# Use values of one vector as index range for another vector

Tags: r, indexing

I provide two vectors here:

```
vec1 <- c(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3)

vec2 <- c(1.96845698, 1.11342534, 0.82580110, 0.35762122, 0.07210485, 0.06046759, 0.93615974, 0.85691566, 0.39439991,
          0.26110080, 1.22082336, 0.71940824, 0.32571803, 0.46358160, 0.16009616, 0.13348428, 1.16801097, 0.30184661, 
          0.51190796, 1.69680701, 0.54418158, 0.74969466, 0.17246107, 0.66953561, 1.02689205, 1.67408220, 1.20311478, 
          0.74049935, 0.55211334, 0.31037724, 0.23620425, 0.34532764, 1.64696898, 0.23094382, 0.67733098, 0.32226374, 
          0.25774802, 0.35768477, 0.27219803, 0.02042260, 0.53784081, 1.27521977, 0.07043151, 0.11879638, 0.13358880)
```

Now I would like to calculate the mean values of different parts from `vec2`. The length of these parts is determined by the values of `vec1`.

So the output is supposed to be a vector of the same length as `vec1`.

The first value of this output vector should be the `mean` of `vec2[1:5]`, since `vec1[1] = 5`. The second value should then be the `mean` of `vec[6:7]`, since `vec[2] = 2` and so forth until the last value of the output vector should correspond to the `mean` of `vec2[43:45]`, since the last value of `vec1` is `3`.

I hope it is clear what I mean.

Here I calculated manually the expected output vector:

```
vec3 <- c(0.8674819, 0.4983137, 0.6256578, 0.7409621, 0.5225631, 0.2523873, 0.7349288, 
          0.9176322, 0.7887523, 0.5765066, 0.3077164, 0.1463103, 0.9065303, 0.1076056)
```

Anybody with an idea, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
tapply(vec2, rep(seq_along(vec1), vec1), mean)
#tapply(vec2, unlist(Map(rep, seq_along(vec1), each=vec1)), mean) #Alternative
#tapply(vec2, inverse.rle(list(lengths=vec1, values=seq_along(vec1))), mean) #Alternative
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#0.8674819 0.4983137 0.6256578 0.7409621 0.5225631 0.2523873 0.7349288 0.9176322 
#        9        10        11        12        13        14 
#0.7887523 0.5765066 0.3077164 0.1463103 0.9065303 0.1076056
```

Comment: Thanks, does perfectly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate function can be used to do this if you rearrange `vec1` slightly:

```
vec1 <- rep(seq_along(vec1), vec1)
aggregate(vec2, list(vec1), mean)$x
# [1] 0.8674819 0.4983137 0.6256578 0.7409621 0.5225631 0.2523873 0.7349288 0.9176322 0.7887523 0.5765066 0.3077164 0.1463103 0.9065303 0.1076056
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as well and is even quite simple. The solution of GKi is just one step shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using purrr

```
# first construct the ranges which is used as input in the purrr-call
range2 <- cumsum(vec1)
range1 <- c(1,cumsum(vec1[1:(length(vec1)-1)])+1)
purrr::map2_dbl(range1, range2, function(x,y) mean(vec2[x:y]))

 [1] 0.8674819 0.4983137 0.6256578 0.7409621 0.5225631 0.2523873 0.7349288 0.9176322 0.7887523 0.5765066 0.3077164 0.1463103 0.9065303 0.1076056
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option could be:

```
tapply(vec2, cumsum(sequence(vec1) == 1), mean)

        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9 
0.8674819 0.4983137 0.6256578 0.7409621 0.5225631 0.2523873 0.7349288 0.9176322 0.7887523 
       10        11        12        13        14 
0.5765066 0.3077164 0.1463103 0.9065303 0.1076056
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(vec1) %>%
    mutate(grp = row_number()) %>% 
    uncount(vec1) %>% 
    mutate(vec2 = vec2) %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(vec2 = mean(vec2))
# A tibble: 14 × 2
     grp  vec2
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1 0.867
 2     2 0.498
 3     3 0.626
 4     4 0.741
 5     5 0.523
 6     6 0.252
 7     7 0.735
 8     8 0.918
 9     9 0.789
10    10 0.577
11    11 0.308
12    12 0.146
13    13 0.907
14    14 0.108
```